# Deriving/interpreting factor loadings from factor analysis

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

Trying factor analysis for the first time . I have a set of data  representing closing prices of s&P index and 10 other stocks .When I run a scree test on a data set(11 variables ) I get eigen value of 2 so I  run  factanal with number of factors =2 , turns out the p value is very low. So I bump the number of factors until 6 after which I run into numerical problems. So I assume i should fail to reject the hypothesis that number of factors is 6.

Now assuming what ever I have described above is the correct way to proceed how do I derive the factor loadings for the 6 factors ? Thanks to the comment I was able to figure out the factor loadings but how to interpret them ?

As you can see lodings are empty for some of the factors.

These are the values :

```
Loadings:
       Factor1  Factor2  Factor3 Factor4 Factor5 Factor6  
SP500  0.597    0.710    0.150   0.107   0.316         
XOM                      0.963   0.124   0.147  -0.165 
BGCP   0.762    0.394    0.148   0.349                 
INTC   0.282    0.935            0.117                 
FB     0.742    0.634    -0.171                         

                     '
```

Answer (score 0):

The `factional()` function returns a `factanal` object. Say you estimated your 2-factor model as follows:

`fmodel <- factanal(data, factors=2)`

You can then obtain the estimated factor loadings using:

`fmodel$loadings`

To check out what else is estimated by the `factional()` function: see `str(fmodel)`

Comment: I see the loadings but for factor 6 it is empty for one of the variables. How do I intepret that ? copy pasted two lines from the output as am not able to  paste the entire output here due to character limitation for comments

Loadings:
      Factor1 Factor2 Factor3 Factor4 Factor5 Factor6
SP500  0.597   0.710   0.150   0.107   0.316         
T                      0.963   0.124   0.147  -0.165